# AdMob in app not showing

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to show a simple test ad in an android app. I was using this github project to test

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/BannerExample

I have also gone through this example https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#configure_gradle

Im using IntelliJ and not Android Studio so havent been able to follow it exactly.

My problem is that the ads dont seem to be appearing. The logs are below and Ive added a couple of ** next to the lines that I think may be problematic. I have also added my code. I have not added anything to the manifest file (I havent seen any example where I have to)

I am using the emulator. Are there certain constraints on what emulator I can use? At the moment I never see any ad or any placeholder where the ad should be.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks

**CODE**

*Layout*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".EntryPoint">

  <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
  </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

*Code*

```
 private AdView mAdView;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
     mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
     AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
     mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
 }

 /** Called when leaving the activity */
 @Override
 public void onPause() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
 }

 /** Called when returning to the activity */
 @Override
 public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.resume();
    }
 }

 /** Called before the activity is destroyed */
 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
 }
```

**LOGS**

```
 5222-5222/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
 5222-5222/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling JIT
 5222-5222/? I/art﹕ JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
 ** 5222-5222/my.app W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/my.app-2/lib/arm
 ** 5222-5222/my.app W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.
 5222-5222/my.app I/WebViewFactory﹕ Loading com.android.webview version 44.0.2403.119 (code 246011900)
 5222-5222/my.app W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/webview/lib/arm
 5222-5222/my.app I/LibraryLoader﹕ Time to load native libraries: 44 ms (timestamps 1048-1092)
 5222-5222/my.app I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
 5222-5250/my.app W/art﹕ Long monitor contention event with owner method=void java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(java.lang.Thread, long, boolean) from Thread.java:4294967294 waiters=0 for 206ms
 5222-5231/my.app W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 91.755ms
 5222-5222/my.app V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider﹕ Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {84fa4d0}
 5222-5222/my.app I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
 5222-5222/my.app I/chromium﹕ [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(120)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
 5222-5222/my.app I/BrowserStartupController﹕ Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
 5222-5222/my.app W/art﹕ Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
 5222-5222/my.app E/SysUtils﹕ ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
 5222-5222/my.app W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(285)] locale_file_path.empty()
 ** 5222-5222/my.app E/libEGL﹕ validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
 ** 5222-5222/my.app E/libEGL﹕ validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
 **   5222-5222/my.app E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(327)] No suitable EGL configs found.
 **  5222-5222/my.app E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_android.cc(23)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
 5222-5222/my.app E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(698)] GLSurface::InitializeOneOff failed
 5222-5250/my.app W/art﹕ Long monitor contention event with owner method=void android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$1.run() from SharedPreferencesImpl.java:90 waiters=1 for 280ms
 5222-5247/my.app W/art﹕ Long monitor contention event with owner method=void java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(java.lang.Thread, long, boolean) from Thread.java:4294967294 waiters=3 for 441ms
 5222-5231/my.app W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 16.275ms
 5222-5222/my.app E/DataReductionProxySettingListener﹕ No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
 5222-5269/my.app W/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ Requires BLUETOOTH permission
 ** 5222-5222/my.app I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
 5222-5231/my.app W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 9.629ms
 5222-5222/my.app I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 5222-5222/my.app D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
 5222-5231/my.app W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 140.144ms
 ** 5222-5246/my.app W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.
 ** 5222-5246/my.app W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.
 5222-5267/my.app W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(423)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
 5222-5222/my.app W/art﹕ Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
 5222-5222/my.app W/AwContents﹕ onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
 5222-5222/my.app W/art﹕ Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
 5222-5222/my.app W/art﹕ Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
 5222-5303/my.app A/chromium﹕ [FATAL:gl_surface_android.cc(58)] Check failed: kGLImplementationNone != GetGLImplementation() (0 vs. 0)
 5222-5303/my.app W/google-breakpad﹕ ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
 5222-5303/my.app W/google-breakpad﹕ Chrome build fingerprint:
 5222-5303/my.app W/google-breakpad﹕ 1.04
 5222-5303/my.app W/google-breakpad﹕ 5
 5222-5303/my.app W/google-breakpad﹕ 023f32a1-4862-425f-a49b-e5b1792614ed
 5222-5303/my.app W/google-breakpad﹕ ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
 5222-5303/my.app E/chromium﹕ ### WebView Version 44.0.2403.119 (code 246011900)
 5222-5303/my.app A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 5303 (GpuThread)
```

Thanks

Comment: emulators do show ads

Comment: add you code that is used to show the ads

Comment: will add now. Thanks

Comment: create emulator that is targeted to google api, not to android

Comment: RNJ let me know if it helps you

Comment: amazing @USKMobility It worked. Thanks a lot! Add as an answer so i can give you the credit. I have been stuck on this for ages. Thanks again!!

Comment: Welcome! added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create emulator that is targeted to Google APIs, not to android.